# java.util.NoSuchElementException while getting ArrayList from HashMap using Iterator

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, hashmap, iterator

My code goes like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<DebtCollectionReport>> mapOfAccounts = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<DebtCollectionReport>>();
  Set<String> agencyNames = agencyWiseAccountMap.keySet();
  Iterator iter = agencyNames.iterator();
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String agency = (String) iter.next();
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<DebtCollectionReport>> tempAccountsMap = agencyWiseAccountMap.get(agency);
    Set<Integer> accountSet = tempAccountsMap.keySet();
    Iterator itr = accountSet.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      mapOfAccounts.put((Integer) itr.next(), tempAccountsMap.get((Integer) itr.next()));
    }
  }
```

I am getting exception trace:

>

```
 java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.cerillion.debtcollection.collector.CollectionExecutor.execute(CollectionExecutor.java:56)
    at com.cerillion.debtcollection.collector.CollectionExecutor.main(CollectionExecutor.java:24)
2017-11-14 05:00:43,733 ERROR  CollectionExecutor             [main      ] Exception occurred while executing Debt Collection java.util.NoSuchElementException
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.cerillion.debtcollection.collector.CollectionExecutor.execute(CollectionExecutor.java:56)
    at com.cerillion.debtcollection.collector.CollectionExecutor.main(CollectionExecutor.java:24)
```

This is occuring for line:

```
mapOfAccounts.put((Integer) itr.next(), tempAccountsMap.get((Integer) itr.next()));
```

What can be the possible reason and how can i resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code block below, you called `hasNext()` once but you have called `next()` two times. `hasNext()` will return true if iteration has more values and  `next()` returns the next element in iteration

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  mapOfAccounts.put((Integer) itr.next(), tempAccountsMap.get((Integer) itr.next()));
}
```

You can change this line accordingly:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  Integer i1 = (Integer) itr.next();
  if(itr.hasNext()){
    mapOfAccounts.put(i1, tempAccountsMap.get((Integer) itr.next()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapOfAccounts.put((Integer) itr.next(), tempAccountsMap.get((Integer) itr.next()));
```

The problem should be with `itr.next()`, every time you called `itr.next()`, the index of the iterator would move a step forward. So the code move 2 steps at this line...
You should with a var to accept the value, then use the var:

```
int accountIdTemp = itr.next();
mapOfAccounts.put((Integer) accountIdTemp , tempAccountsMap.get((Integer) accountIdTemp ));
```

Hope this help.